# Which Linux distros does the nVidia 600 series support?

Tags: linux

I would like to know which distros are supported by the nVidia 600 series , I tried Manjaro&Elementary OS , both failed and then Ubuntu which worked , but I don't like Ubuntu so are there any other distros which have support for that card series ? (I am guessing Linux Mint and other Ubuntu based distros do , but preferably something lightweight like Manjaro/Crunchbang).

Comment: It didn't work is vague clarify that aspect of your problem. What distro was that distro based on?

Comment: If one supports it, all will, you just have to find out what tweaks are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

NVidia support in Linux could be described as a travesty at best.   I've never used that card specifically but I've had pretty good luck with NVidia cards and Archlinux.

The wiki page is pretty helpful.  I'd try the'lts' package listed.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA

And the user repository has driver packages as well.

https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/nvidia-all/